# Return all column names in case of tied highest value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe.

```
>df
 A    B    C    D    E
 0.1  0.8  0.3  0.8  0.3
```

I want to get column names with highest value. However if I used

```
maxcols = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

this only give first column (B) in this case, while I want output, something like [B,D].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can try

```
s=df.eq(df.max(1),axis=0)
s[s].stack().index.get_level_values(1)
Index(['B', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: thx. So if I have more rows, I should just iter through them? Is there no way to broadcast it, because I have a rather large number of rows.

Comment: @Martan when you do stack , you can get them with multiple rows `s[s].stack().index`